# How to stop Excel from reopening file after saving as PDF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

In Excel 2013 (and probably earlier versions) when you save a file as a pdf, Excel says

> Acrobat PDFMaker needs to save the file before continuing. Do you want PDFMaker to save the file and continue?

When you click that, it asks you where to save the file, and then the file is closed. I'm fine with all that. What I would like to stop is the reopening of the file after it's saved as a PDF. My usage, and I'm assuming most peoples', is that you don't save a file as PDF until you are done editing it, so I don't know why it reopens it. Anyone know how to stop this?

Answer (score 2):

PDFMaker is a program/Office add-on from Adobe, not part of Office.

If, instead, you use Office's internal `Save As..` and pick `PDF`, it gives you an option as to whether you'd like it to open after saving (aka 'Publishing') or not.

[image: Save As PDF options]

Perhaps PDFMaker has a similar option but I can't find documentation of it, and I'm assuming you already checked for that anyway. :)